# Visual Studio not showing the device option for Cordova project(Windows 10)

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova

I have created a cordova project in visual studio. For testing the app, the solution platform bar only shows the "Simulate in Browser .." options. The device option is not showing. I have android sdk and android studio installed. I can see my device when i run the `adb devices` in cmd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto **Tools > Options > Tools for Apache Cordova > Environment Variable Overrides**.

[image]

Most probably the **ANDROID_HOME** check box might be empty. Copy your android sdk location into it. For me its **C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk**. Now restart visual studio. The "Device" option will be there.

Comment: still don't see that option

Comment: @knigalye Have you added the ANDROID_HOME location to your path variable..? You should have the JAVA_HOME in your path variable as well.